# Banco de dados com bug junto ao node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Durante os testes, o banco de dados se mostrou com um comportamento estranho de sobrepor dados, se cadastrado um usuário ao cadastro do segundo não listam os dois, o segundo sobrepõe o primeiro, e ao momento de desligar o server ou quando cai ele zera o banco de dados.

Segue o código:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('toughts2', 'root', '1234', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect:'mysql',
})
try{
    sequelize.authenticate()
    console.log('conectado com sucesso')
} catch (err) {
    console.log('não foi possível conectar')
    console.log(err)
}
module.exports = sequelize
```

[projeto educacional]

Qual o meu erro e como posso resolvê-lo?

Answer (score -1):

Você não postou o código dos models na pergunta, mas é possível que esteja com a configuração de sincronização de modelos `"ativa"`.

Veja documentação relevante [aqui](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/model-synchronization/)

- Model.sync() - Cria a tabela se ela não existir (e não faz nada se já existir)
- Model.sync({force: true }) - Isso cria a tabela, descartando-a primeiro se ela já existir
- Model.sync({ alter: true }) - Verifica qual é o estado atual da tabela no banco de dados (quais colunas ela possui, quais são seus tipos de dados, etc), e então realiza as alterações necessárias na tabela para fazer combina com o modelo.

---

> Embora sync() seja uma ferramenta muito útil durante o
> desenvolvimento, ela não foi projetada para ser usada em produção e o
> uso de suas opções alterar ou forçar pode levar à perda de dados.
> Consulte Migrações para saber como atualizar o esquema do seu banco de
> dados em produção.

Portanto use com cautela.